# How to Handle Button OncClick Fragments Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Can someone help me how to handle button clicks on fragments? I'm having an error when I go to my fragment in profile. When I click the button on fragment_profile, I always get an error.

Here's my code:

For my Main Activity Class:

```
    package com.the.healthescort;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    Context CTX = this;
    public int see;
    public String cc="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Mod();


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
       //
    }



     public void Mod(){
         DatabaseOperation DOp = new DatabaseOperation(CTX);
         Cursor cr = DOp.getInformation(DOp);
         if (cr != null && cr.getCount()>0){
            cr.moveToFirst();
           startManagingCursor(cr);
           for(int i=0;i<cr.getCount();i++){
           String x = cr.getString(3);
           String y = cr.getString(4);

           String c = x.replace("\"", "");
           String r = c.replace("' ", ".");
           double get = Double.parseDouble(r);
           int z = (int) get;
           double w = get % z;
           double roundOff = Math.round(w*10);
           int ans = (z*12)+ (int)roundOff;

         String g = y.replace(" lbs","");
         double h = Double.parseDouble(g);

         double total = (h/(ans*ans))*703;

           }


         }else{
             Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add_Profile.class);
             startActivity(k);
             finish();
         }



     }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;

        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                tx.replace(R.id.container,PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1));
                tx.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                tx.replace(R.id.container,new profile_fragment());
                tx.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                break;
        }



    }


    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {

        switch (number) {
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:


                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);

                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public int check;
        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {

            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;

        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }



        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }



}
```

My Fragment code:

```
package com.the.healthescort;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class profile_fragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        profile_fragment f = new profile_fragment();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_fragment, container, false);

        Button a = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.sana);

        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View view){
                TextView b = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gumana);
                b.setText("Click!");
            }

        });


        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the error? post the error's stack trace please..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View view){
       TextView b = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gumana);
       b.setText("Click!");
}
```

in this case, `view` is the object on which you called `setOnClickListener`, the button you called `a`. If you call `view.findViewById(R.id.yourid)`, on a View's subclass, what the system does is to check if the id you passed as parameter is equal to the one of the view on which you are calling findViewById. It the view is subclass of ViewGroup's, then the system looks for the provided id among the ViewGroup's children. In your case the view's id is `R.id.sana`, and you are passing `R.id.gumana` as parameter. Since the ids don't match the system returns null. You probably have declared the `TextView`, inside `fragment_profile_fragment.xml`.

Change

```
TextView b = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gumana);
```

with

```
TextView b = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gumana);
```